# React -how to convert a <div> to input

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, input, contenteditable

I have a table that each row that has some `td` that here these 2 `td` are important for me and I want to change them: `name` & `family`.
I want to change each `name` or `family` `td` when the user clicks on it.
how can I handle this event?

this is my table `td` :

```
finalList.map((i, index) => {
  return (
    <tr className="contactItem" id={i.id} key={i.id}>
      <td>{String(index + 1).padStart(2, "0")}).</td>
      <td id="editName" onClick={(e) => inlineEditHandler(e, i.name)}>{i.name}</td>
      <td id="editFamily" onClick={(e) => inlineEditHandler(e, i.family)}>{i.family}</td>
      <td>
        {String(i.numbers[0]).substring(7, 11) +
          "***" +
          String(i.numbers[0]).substring(0, 4)}
      </td>
      <td className="itemBTNS">
        <button
          className="deleteBTN"
          onClick={() => contactDeleteHandler(i.id)}
        >
          X
        </button>
        <button
          className="editBTN"
          onClick={() => contactEditHandler(i)}
        >
          Edit
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
})
```

I want to set this event for the second and third `td`.
And note that I don't want to use the `contentEditable` attribute.

```
  inlineEditHandler = (e, i) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: i,
    });
  };
```

`editName` and `editFamily` are my states.
What should I do in the `inlineEditHandler` function or other stuff to change the tagName from `td` to input or something like this?

Comment: Why contentEditable cannot be used? If contentEditable cannot be used, you may change the td content to an input box.

Comment: I don't want to use contentEditable because I think it changes the DOM. Doesn't it?
@TheKNVB